# PHP . How to configure default $PATH environment variable

Tags: php, apache

On my web server i found that when i run PHP then PATH variable is just '/bin'.

getenv('PATH') returns '/bin'

this is why some calls of exec() and system() doesn't work for programs located in /usr/bin and other standard locations.

The user which is used to run PHP has the correct PATH variable but it is ignored.

How to configure PHP (or apache? ) so I have this variable correct inside PHP scripts?

I know how to change it in PHP, but I don't want to touch PHP scripts. It is better for me to change some server configuration.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I already found what i need. this is option env_path  in suphp config